# Copy multiple files to remote location and show progress details in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files from local machines to remote location.
When i run the script it will check folder exist on remote location. If it is not created then it will create a directory. Once directory created it will copy all files from source location.

My script is working fine for that but i want output on screen what files are being copied.

Below are the code that is working fine to copy the files but it is not showing file names being copied.

```
$machine = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$dest= "\\192.168.1.5\d$\test\"

$source = "C:\windows\logs\"

$newPath = Join-Path $dest -childpath $machine

 if(!(Test-Path -Path $newPath )){
        New-Item $newPath -type directory
             foreach ($file in $source)
             {
                    write-host "Copying Files: " $file  -foregroundcolor DarkGreen -backgroundcolor white
                    Copy-Item $file -Destination $newPath -force

             }

        }else{
        foreach ($file in $source)
        {
        write-host "Copying Files: " $file  -foregroundcolor DarkGreen -backgroundcolor white
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $newPath -recurse -Force

        }   
    }
```

Comment: There is a commandlet `Write-Progress` which should come in handy.
Beneath that: Is there a reason why you have the same copy-code inside the if-block and inside the else-block? Why not just go for an if to ensure that the folder exists and copy beneath all that in a single operation?

Comment: this script is still in development phase. If folder not exist then it will create folder and copy the files. So, i put one copy files command under test path and another one without test path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work. I altered the if-statement so you don't have redundant code and adapted $source, so the foreach will work with your write-progress

```
$machine = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$dest= "\\192.168.1.5\d$\test\"

$sourcePath = 'C:\windows\logs\'

$source = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath

$newPath = Join-Path $dest -childpath $machine

if(!(Test-Path -Path $newPath )){
    New-Item $newPath -type directory
}

$count = $source.count
$operation = 0

foreach ($file in $source)
{
    $operation++
    write-host 'Copying File: ' $file  -foregroundcolor DarkGreen -backgroundcolor white
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Copying data' -Status 'Progress' -PercentComplete ($operation/$count*100)
    Copy-Item $file -Destination $newPath -force

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.